# Rack - Erro ao Publicar Plugin do Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Estou criando um plugin para o Redmine que irá atuar como gerador e publicador de projetos dentro de um repositório, porém estou tendo problemas ao acessar o meu botão de <kbd>Publicar projeto</kbd>.

A função que criei para publicar o projeto se encontra no mesmo arquivo dentro do diretório `/gerar_versao_projeto/lib/client` do plugin. Terá ela que se comunicar com um arquivo  `server_versao.java` que se encontra em meu servidor e é responsável por fazer todo o processo de publicação e retornar erro ou sucesso para o Redmine. Porém todos os dados foram codificados e debugados. Creio que seja um problema com Rack pois a mesma hash que é gerada para o botão de <kbd>Gerar</kbd> está sendo utilizada pelo botão de <kbd>Publicar</kbd>.

Já verifiquei outras possibilidades de erro e a mais possível no momento seria esta.

Alguem teria alguma idéia?

Comment: se for possível poste seu código

Answer (score 1):

## FUNÇÃO DE GERAR PROJETO

def exec_client

```
begin
  hostname = Setting.plugin_gerar_versao_projeto['ip_number']
  port = Setting.plugin_gerar_versao_projeto['port_number']
  s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)
  s.puts "MSG_RV"
  @project = Project.find_by_identifier(params[:id])
  @repositories = @project.repositories
  @repository = @repositories.first

  if params[:branch] == nil
    s.puts @repository.name
  else
    s.puts params[:branch]
  end

  msg_final = s.read
  puts "MSG_FINAL = #{msg_final}"
  if msg_final =~ /MSG_ERR/
     display_alert l(:alert_error)
  elsif msg_final =~ /MSG_SUC/
      display_alert l(:release_done)
  end

  s.close               # Close the socket when done
rescue
  display_alert l(:alert_error)
end
```

end

---

### O mesmo se aplica para a função de Publicação, mudando somente a condição de Mensagem final:

```
msg_final = s.read
      puts "MSG_FINAL = #{msg_final}"
      if msg_final =~ /MSG_ERR/
         display_alert l(:alert_error)
      elsif msg_final =~ /MSG_SUC/
          display_alert l(:publish_done)
```

### end

Ambas as funções criam um soquete e fazem uma conexão através da porta 13000 do meu servidor de aplicação/repositório. Quando as funções são executadas, retornam uma mensagem para o REDMINE, que por sua vez retorna SUCESSFULL ou ERROR.

O que estou notando é que ao clicar nos botões , ambos estão utilzando os mesmos parâmetros no conceito de RACK:

---

```
started POST "/projects/teste/repository/exec_client" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-26 08:44:07 -0300
Processing by RepositoriesController#exec_client as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ta+3n7z4wGBjnBBaovBAEc9D3oAePYwSLUIhVpciR2c=", "id"=>"teste"}
```

---

### e

```
  Started POST "/projects/teste/repository/exec_release" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-26 08:43:31 -0300
Processing by RepositoriesController#exec_release as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ta+3n7z4wGBjnBBaovBAEc9D3oAePYwSLUIhVpciR2c=", "id"=>"teste"}
```

---

Caso precisem de mais algum fonte, estarei aqui.

Comment: O problema foi resolvido. Devido a um s mal colocado em ambas as funções Setting.plugin_gerar_versao_projeto['ip_number'], ele não recebia os parâmetros de IP e porta.